# Как получить из кода только ссылку, python

Tags: python, youtube-api

Всем привет, как мне получить из данного кода только ссылку на видею ютуб?
В данном случае (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sl59t_OBBKc), суть в том что ссылка есть, но мне ничего кроме неё не нужно

```
#pip install youtube-search-python
from youtubesearchpython import VideosSearch

channelsSearch = VideosSearch('Привет песня', limit = 1)

print(channelsSearch.result(1))
```

Comment: попробуйте преобразовать 1 элемент списка в список, возможно вы сможете потом извлечь из него только ссылку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, надо просто разобраться в структуре результата и обратиться к нужному элементу.

Здесь работает такое:

```
print(channelsSearch.result(1)['result'][-1]['link'])
```

Но нужно быть аккуратнее, так как ответ от api в каком-то случае может изменить структуру списка в 'result', и обращение к -1 элементу станет некорректным.